# Linux idle usage of hard disk, wearing out my SSD?

Tags: ssd, linux-mint

I built a new system a few months ago, with an i5, 8GB ram, and a 240GB SSD for system and a 3TB data disk. I'm running Mint 18 Sarah. I am still somewhat a noob with Linux, so there may well be some very obvious stuff I'm missing.

I did some googling while setting up, to see what sort of things I could do to reduce the number of writes to SSD, and found sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/ssd, which suggested a number of optimisations like noatime to avoid updating file information when it's simply read, reducing swappiness, reducing the browser cache etc.

In order to see how much writing was occurring, I left the machine idle for 24 hours, idle being nothing I'd asked it to do apart from running an smb server, and when I did an fstrim it trimmed around 200GB, which is practically the entire SSD size.

I have noticed it trim 340MB after being left idle for 1 minute, though usually over this time it's more likely to be 50MB or zero.

Many questions.

Am I interpreting the amount trimmed figure correctly? Are these writes to the SSD, or is it something else, like the SSD reorganising itself, or what?

Does Mint (ubuntu?) normally write this much to HD? It seems a lot. Is it a lot?

Does 'sudo fstrim -v /' trim only the SSD, or does it also trim the data disk on /media/me/data_disk? If so, I may be worrying over nothing. How do I exclude the data disc from the trim?

How do I find out what is doing all the writing (I don't know my way around interrogating the running processes yet).

I have seen something about making a ramfs and mounting var there, which I've not girded my loins to do yet, would I expect that to help a little bit, or a lot? How do I find out?

Without me asking it to during setup, I do notice that there are 16 ramdisks, each one 64MB in size, which seems an odd default configuration. Again, I've not got around to 'fixing' this, even if it does need fixing.

Given that I'm going to have to learn something new to reduce this, what should I be learning?

Comment: Swappiness is probably the first thing to look at, and a value of 10 works well: with your 8GB this should minimise swapping, if not eliminate it. If you don't need to hibernate, you might also consider using a file instead of a partition for swapping, as this can be easily recreated periodically in a different area of the disc. Both these topics are well covered [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/218083). To monitor disc activity, `htop` can easily be configured to show which programs which are making the greatest number of disc reads or writes.

Comment: htop seems to have a lot of info there, man htop mentions only l = lsof, is this the tool to see how much data is being written where by the process, at the moment, it only seems to show file descriptors / open files?

Comment: `lsof` is a utility to list open files: it does not show disc activity. `htop` does not by default show disc reads and writes, but they can be added as columns and either can be selected for the sort order.

Comment: OK, I've figured out how to add IO_WRITE_RATE, WCHAR, WBYTE to the columns, are there any more I should be interested in. The main culprits seem to be marco and the mate panel, at least when running htop, and chromium-browser when that's open. Is my assumption that the size reported by fstrim -v is that which has been written and then discarded, correct?

Comment: I've not used `fstrim`, so I can't comment on what it reports. As far as `htop` is concerned, the read and write byte totals are the first to look at, though this will include network and other I/O; the disc I/O rates, as well as the page fault totals and swap use will also be of interest.